# How to generate a zero padded sequence of numbers upto a given limit using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column to `df.Dataframe` as follows:

```
VAL001
VAL002
VAL003
...
...
...
VAL498
VAL499
VAL500
```

I wondering there is a way to quickly generate it without type it one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with `zfill`:

```
df['New Column'] = ['VAL'+str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1,501)]
```

or:

```
df['New Column'] = [str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1,501)]
df['New Column'] = 'VAL'+df['New Column']
```

or:

```
df['New Column'] = range(1,501)
df['New Column'] = 'VAL'+df['New Column'].astype('str').str.zfill(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialise a Series from `range` (or `arange`), and use `str.zfill` to pad zeros on the left:

```
n = 10
pd.Series(range(1, n+1), dtype=str).str.zfill(3).radd('VAL')

0    VAL001
1    VAL002
2    VAL003
3    VAL004
4    VAL005
5    VAL006
6    VAL007
7    VAL008
8    VAL009
9    VAL010
dtype: object
```

Change `n=500` for your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Borrow [cs95's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267699/7964527) setting up

```
'VAL'+s.str.pad(width=3,fillchar='0')
Out[404]: 
0    VAL001
1    VAL002
2    VAL003
3    VAL004
4    VAL005
5    VAL006
6    VAL007
7    VAL008
8    VAL009
9    VAL010
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the value without typing one by one using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

lst=[('VAL'+('%0*d' % (3,i+1))) for i in range(500)]
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          0
0    VAL001
1    VAL002
2    VAL003
3    VAL004
4    VAL005
5    VAL006
..      ...
495  VAL496
496  VAL497
497  VAL498
498  VAL499
499  VAL500

[500 rows x 1 columns]
```